# Kivy Python Can not do anything after starting GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, kivy

After starting the GUI nothing else is able to get executed. For example the "Hello" does not get printed out. Why?

code: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15O8DwL04DdY6V-Tl-vuc7yIwDL_AFRBh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add your code here, don't link to it offsite

Comment: I am sorry but it does not work because the code is too long. :/

Comment: You have to make it minimal (as far as the example goes) and also add more explanation. There’s a reason it doesn’t fit as it is now.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your app starts at your call to `ChatBot().run()`. That call does not return until the app stops, so your`print` will not be executed until your app stops.